# Using sum in eloquent laravel when have quantity and price

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with my projects e-commerce
in,in this problem i have 2 tables.

Table Products

```
ID     | Name_products   | Price
P1     | Product A       | 2000
P2     | Product B       | 5000
P3     | Product C       | 7500
```

Table User Carts

```
ID     | User_id    | Product_id  | Quantity
C1     | User1      | P1          | 2
C2     | User1      | P2          | 1
```

I have using this query eloquent :

```
$totalPricec = MyCart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
               ->select('products.nama_produk', 'products.id as product_id','products.price''my_carts.quantity','my_carts.id as id')
               ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'my_carts.product_id')
               ->sum('price');
```

but i got price is **7000** (product A = 2000 + product B = 5000)

should be **9000** (product A = 2000 * 2 + product B = 5000 * 1)

how i can get the total price actually?

Comment: I think you missed the actual multiplication. `'products.price''my_carts.quantity'` shouldn't it be `products.price*my_carts.quantity as total` and then sum `total`? But it looks weird. Maybe something like this would be better? Inside select `DB::raw('sum(products.price*my_carts.quantity) as total')`, that way you can get rid of the sum at the end

Comment: @user3532758 what is that?

Answer (score 4):

I using this query

```
$totalPricec = MyCart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
           ->select('products.nama_produk', 'products.id as product_id','products.price''my_carts.quantity','my_carts.id as id')
           ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'my_carts.product_id')
           ->sum(DB::raw('products.price * my_carts.quantity'));
```

and thats work :)

thank you for user **@user3532758**

Comment: No reason to use `select()` here.